# can't declare array in C# POST request

Tags: c#, arrays, post, request

```
var resultHttpPost = ZennoPoster.HttpPost("http://box.chomikuj.pl/services/ChomikBoxService.svc",
"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><s:Envelope s:encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/' xmlns:s='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><s:Body><Auth xmlns='http://chomikuj.pl/'><name>topbarlogin</name><passHash>e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e</passHash><ver>4</ver></Auth></s:Body></s:Envelope>", 
"text/xml;charset=utf-8", "", "UTF-8", ZennoLab.InterfacesLibrary.Enums.Http.ResponceType.HeaderAndBody, 30000, "", "Mozilla/5.0", true, 1, string[] headers = new String[3]{ "a", "b", "c" }, "", false);
```

I have problem with this:

```
string[] headers = new String[3]{ "a", "b", "c" }
```

I still get the error and I don't know how to declare it.

Answer (score 0):

just delete "string[] headers = " part

```
var resultHttpPost = ZennoPoster.HttpPost("http://box.chomikuj.pl/services/ChomikBoxService.svc","<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><s:Envelope s:encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/' xmlns:s='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><s:Body><Auth xmlns='http://chomikuj.pl/'><name>topbarlogin</name><passHash>e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e</passHash><ver>4</ver></Auth></s:Body></s:Envelope>", "text/xml;charset=utf-8", "", "UTF-8", ZennoLab.InterfacesLibrary.Enums.Http.ResponceType.HeaderAndBody, 30000, "", "Mozilla/5.0", true, 1, new String[3]{ "a", "b", "c" }, "", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write just:

```
new String[3]{ "a", "b", "c" }
```

and not:

```
string[] headers = new String[3]{ "a", "b", "c" }
```